# Is it possible to program Atmega8 on a development board designed for Atmega16?

Tags: atmega, development-tools

I'm trying to load a hex file to **Atmega8** but it seems impossible to do it directly on a normal bread board so I'm planning to buy this development board.

It is the only board that my local store can provide. Is it possible to program Atmega8 in this thing?

[image]

Comment: Atmega16 is 40 pin (wide) PDIP while Atmega8 is 28 pin (narrow) PDIP. So it might not fit, looking at that socket (hard to judge from the picture).

Answer (score 1):

Usually with these types of programmers it's good to look at the software that your programming it with and see what it supports, if the chip you want to program is in the list of the firmware program software then it might work.

You could do is just contact the programmer company and see what they support